# Reflow table generated in loop not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, html-table

I am generating a **reflow table** in loop in **jQuery mobile** after the **ajax success**. However the problem is the table is not responsive. On small screens the table generated is supposed to work by collapsing the table columns into a stacked presentation that looks like blocks of label/data pairs for each row. When I output the table markup I generate from loop and copy/paste into a separate page, the table looks fine and is responsive.

**The html I generate is:**

```
<table data-role="table" id="time-table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Linje</th>
         <th>Destination</th>
         <th>Nästa tur (min)</th>
         <th>Därefter</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <th>7</th>
         <td>Resecentrum</td>
         <td>Nu</td>
         <td>11</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>7</th>
         <td>Ö Lugnet via Resecentrum</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>51</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Looks like this in small screen **when I copy the markup generated and paste in a separate file** and this is `what I need`.

[image]

However when I do it dynamically with the code:

```
success: function(data){
    //Generate table header and populate.
var thdata1 = "<th>"+data[2]+"</th>";
var thdata2 = "<th>"+data[3]+"</th>";
var thdata3 = "<th>"+data[4]+"</th>";
var thdata4 = "<th>"+data[6]+"</th>";

    var tblrow = $("<tr></tr>");
var thead = $("<thead></thead>");
var table = $("<table data-role=\"table\" id=\"time-table\" data-mode=\"reflow\" class=\"ui-responsive table-stroke\">");

tblrow.append(thdata1);
tblrow.append(thdata2);
tblrow.append(thdata3);
tblrow.append(thdata4);

    thead.append(tblrow);
table.append(thead)

    //Generate table body and populate.
var row = $("<tr>");
var flag = 0;
var tbody = $('<tbody>');
$.each(data, function(key, val){
    if(key >= 8){
    if(key%4 != 3){
      if(flag == 0)
        row.append("<th>"+val+"</th>");
      else
        row.append("<td>"+val+"</td>");
      flag++;
    }
    else if(key%4 == 3){
      row.append("<td>"+val+"</td>");
      tbody.append(row);
      row = $("<tr>");
      flag = 0;
    }
     }
     });
   table.append(tbody);
   table.appendTo("#contbl");
   console.log($("#contbl").html());
}
```

It generates a normal layout unresponsive table like in the image below which retains the same structure even in smaller screen. Also the css looks out of place in this layout. I am using the default table `class="ui-responsive table-stroke"` as provided by jQM.

[image]

The markup I generate is working fine. I cannot figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: where is `my-custom-breakpoint` css class needed to break the table when viewed on smaller screen ? also have you tried to refresh the page as I know when dynamically generated html is added you will need to refresh the page content using `$('page_id').trigger('pagecreate');`

Comment: I am using the default class `class="ui-responsive table-stroke"` which should also do I guess. Because when I copy paste the html generated it is working fine.

Comment: @AntonBelev: Yes indeed I was missing that point `$('page_id').trigger('pagecreate');`. Now it works, thanks. Post as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create dynamically html like in your case you have to update the page content using

```
$('page_id').trigger('pagecreate');
```