# jQuery reflow table inside collapsible-set not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am very new to jQuery, if this had been asked many time please point me to the right direction. I am trying to put a reflow table inside the a collapsible div.

```
   $.each(info, function (i, area) {
    // Clone block
    var item_area_block = area_block.cloneNode(false);
    var item_area_title = area_title.cloneNode(false);
    var item_area_display =  area_display.cloneNode(false);
    var item_area_table = area_table.cloneNode(false);
    var item_area_table_body = area_table_body.cloneNode(false);

    // Create title
    item_area_title.innerHTML = area.area_name;

    // Create table content
    item_area_table.setAttribute("id", "category_table_"+i);
    $.each(area.sport_category, function (cat_number, category) {
        var table_tr = area_table_tr.cloneNode(false);
        var table_th = document.createElement('th');

        table_th.innerHTML = category.sport_name;
        table_tr.appendChild(table_th);
        $.each(category.events, function (i, date) {
             var table_date_td = area_table_td.cloneNode(false);
             table_date_td.innerHTML = date.url;
             table_tr.appendChild(table_date_td);
        });


        item_area_table_body.appendChild(table_tr);
    });

    // Thread
    var item_area_table_thread = document.createElement('thead');
    var thread_table_tr = area_table_tr.cloneNode(false);
    var thread_table_th = document.createElement('th');
    var thread_table_th2 = document.createElement('th');
    thread_table_th.innerHTML = "test";
    thread_table_th2.innerHTML = "test2";
    thread_table_tr.appendChild(thread_table_th);
    thread_table_tr.appendChild(thread_table_th2);
    item_area_table_thread.appendChild(thread_table_tr);
    item_area_table.appendChild(item_area_table_thread);

    item_area_table.appendChild(item_area_table_body);
    <!-- $("#category_table_"+i).table("refresh"); -->
    <!-- item_area_display.appendChild(item_area_table); -->

    // Add content block to container
    item_area_block.appendChild(item_area_title); // Title
    item_area_block.appendChild(item_area_table); // Content
    container.appendChild(item_area_block);

});

//Reflesh
$("#area_table").promise().done(function () {
    $(this).find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({
        refresh: true
    });
});
$('info-page').trigger('pagecreate');
});
```

A working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/a8VZu/) and here is my [failed example](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinchows/jb3x7/9/).

If I copy the table's html code to another page, it seem to work fine.
I also try the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807961/reflow-table-generated-in-loop-not-responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to initialize the jQM table widget as well as refreshing the collapsible:

```
$("#area_table").promise().done(function () {
    $(this).find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({
        refresh: true
    });
    $(this).find('table').table();
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jb3x7/19/)**

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Didn't realize I have to initialize it.

Comment: Dynamic content is added after normal jQM initialization, so you have to initialize. If you add content to an existing widget, then refresh is enough.